# Are Winterbash questions auto-migrated?

Tags: support, winterbash

I'm pretty sure I asked the following two questions on the [IT Security Meta](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/) site.

[Where do I find all the SE sites that support hats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159402/where-do-i-find-all-the-se-sites-that-support-hats)

[When are hats rewarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159403/when-are-hats-rewarded)

However, they seem to have instantaneously been pulled over to MSO without even leaving a shred of evidence on either site that the questions were actually migrated.  (It appears as if the questions were posted directly to MSO.)  Is this an automatic function for questions tagged [winterbash](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winterbash)?

Note:  I'm *deliberately* making sure to ask *this* question on the Sec.SE Meta to test my theory.

Comment: Nope.  Looks like I'm hallucinating and the questions *were* originally on MSO I guess.  Could swear I'd started them on Meta.Sec.SE though.

Answer (score 1):

Clever tactic- that will get you an extra hat:-)

No- it doesn't automatically pull them over to MSO

Comment: Nah, I need someone to vote on this before I get the hat.  :-(

Comment: What, like that?

Comment: Thanks!  Too bad it's not a Metaltech hat.